# ace editor change event and setvalue

Tags: javascript, events, ace-editor

I am listening on ACE editor's change event to handle with user's input while sometimes I will do `setvalue()` by js.

So is there a way to avoid the `setvalue()` triggering the change event?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is no way to avoid change event.
But because change event is fired synchronously, you can set a flag to not handle the events created by you. Something like

```
var fromSetValue = false;
editor.on("change", function() {
    if (!fromSetValue) {
        // user input
    }
})

fromSetValue = true;
editor.setValue("hi")
fromSetValue = false;
```

Comment: I think the change event is fired asynchronously, correct me if I'm wrong. Hence there is no way to make sure that `change` is fired before `fromSetValue = false`. Thus your solution is not guaranteed to work in every case, I'm afraid.

Comment: You need to put `fromSetValue = false` inside the callback.

Comment: change event is fired synchronously

Comment: Note that the change event is fired before the content is done loading, so if you try to do something like setValue(); goto line# it won't work in a change listener.

Answer (score 0):

You may suppress firing events before setting a new value (and/or doing other manipulations with editor), and restore it after.

```
const editorValueChangeHandler = () => {
  console.log('Value handled', editor.getValue());
};

editor.off('change', editorValueChangeHandler);
editor.session.setValue('newValue');
// ... other operations with editor...
editor.on('change', editorValueChangeHandler);
```